# Get multiple rows from foreach

Tags: php, html, database, foreach

So on my project I have posts. And basically they include the post time and post content. Now here's my issue, I can only figure out how to retrieve one row instead of post content *and* post time. Here's my code

```
$posts = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $posts[] =  $row['post_content'];
}
```

And how I'm returning

```
<?php
foreach($posts as $post) {
   $post; 
?>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="post">
        <h1 class="message">
        <?php
            echo $post;
        ?>
        </h1>
        <p class="time">4 minutes ago</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I've tried

```
$posts = array();
$time = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $posts[] =  $row['post_content'];
        $time[] =  $row['post_time'];
    }
```

But that doesn't work. I've ran out of ideas. Any help would be great. Also if there is a cleaner way to do this, it would be nice knowing how. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested arrays:

```
$posts = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $posts[] =  array(
        'post_content' => $row['post_content'],
        'time' => $row['post_time']     
    );

}
```

Then your echo needs to reference `$post['post_content']` and `$post['time']`.

Comment: Working nice. Thanks.

Comment: great, glad to help. don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your're using $post = value, this will overwrite your value each time, try:

```
array_push($posts, $row['post_content']);
```

inside of your while loop

Answer (score -1):

You could simply generate your HTML within the while loop. Otherwise, you might like to populate your posts array directly with [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) -

```
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

and use it as you have been, e.g -

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?> 
    <article>            
        <h1> <?php echo $post['title']; ?> </h1>               
        <p> <?php echo $post['content']; ?> </p>
    </article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.